# Module compiled against a different Node.js version - SQLite3 error

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

Im trying to use SQLite3 in my electron app but i keep getting the error -

```
Uncaught Error: The module '\\?\\Desktop\Test\NHS-BDonor\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v4.0-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 69. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:160:31)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:160:31)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:533)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:640)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\Desktop\Test\NHS-BDonor\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\Desktop\Test\NHS-BDonor\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js:190)
```

Package.json file -

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "4.0.5",
    "electron-builder": "^20.38.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.4",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.6",
    "update-electron-app": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

I've tried numerous solution on stackoverflow and youtube but none seem to be working. Any input/help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Same error it was time spoiler

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an issue with electron-builder, see [this issue on github](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3660).

As a workaround I have fixed the electron version to 4.0.3 (latest still working version), but you can also find [another workaround](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3660#issuecomment-465461491) in the mentioned issue ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the info.